# How to stop gstreamer elements from printing to stdout?

Tags: stdout, gstreamer, verbose

Some of the gstreamer elements that I use keep spamming "useless" (a matter of opinion) information to stdout, anyway of muting a specific gstreamer element?

Comment: Is it a publicly accessible element? Normally, all elements use GStreamer-provided debug macros that only print to stdout when you tell them to using the `GST_DEBUG` environment variable.

Comment: Yes its public and verbose AF.

Comment: Okay then, can you please tell which one so people can take a look at it?

Comment: omxh264enc is one of them